# Autocomplete jquery Plugin not working ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

-Hello Guys , I am trying to use autocomplete in jquery, this is my code :

-This action is placed on a controller named Agence in an area called Admin.

```
public JsonResult GetAgences(string term)
        {
            return Json(_agenceRepo.SearchByNom(term), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

-Here is the method of the repository that returns the Value to JSon :

```
public IList<Agence> SearchByNom(string nom)
        {
            return _context.Agences.Where(a => a.Nom.Contains(nom)).ToArray();
        }
```

-This is the jquery code :

```
<label for="completeMe">Find:</label>
<input type="text" id="completeMe" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#completeMe").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetAgences", "Agence")',
            minLength: 1
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

-All of this code is placed in one page, the one that has the searching field.
-Here is my JQuery references on the master page :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src=  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

-I followed all the needed steps but nothing happens when I want results of search. I suspect that the problem is in my jQuery references. Thank You.

Comment: Something that could be an issue, I see you are rendering a bundle called ~/bundles/jquery then directly after linking in jquery manually in a script tag. Make sure you are not loading multiple jquery files.

Comment: I left only one, same problem

Comment: Do you get any errors on the page? Also, what does the network traffic look like? Do you see a response in the console?

Comment: I am not so familier with jquery, so can you tell what shall I do exactly to see the network traffic ? and how can I get the console inti chrome ?

Comment: Press F12 and click on Console tab, is there any javascript error?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with your ajax call, you have not specified the param. 
Do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#completeMe").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetAgences", "Agence")',
        data: {term: 'xyz'}
        minLength: 1
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can yout tell me what the line data: {term: 'xyz'} means ?